# Jquery update a localstorage item with updated array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to update a localstorage item with a new updated array. The problem I'm facing is that I just can't update my array properly and send it to the localstorage item. So what I'm trying is to get the localstaorage item first. Then look for an existing object with key `qid`. If that is found then update the `qty` value with `qP_val`. That I was able to get to work but how can I update the existing array `stored_quote` with an updated version of this array?

```
function updateQuoteProduct(qP, qP_val){

    var stored_quote = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("iwQuote")); 

    obj = stored_quote.findIndex((obj => obj.qid === qP));

    stored_quote[obj].qty = parseInt(qP_val)

    /* now I want to push the updated array back to */ 
    /* the original stored_quote array and replace  */ 
    /* the old object                               */
    /********************************************** */
    
    stored_quote.push(stored_quote[obj])
    

    /* update the localStorage again with new data */
    localStorage.setItem("iwQuote", JSON.stringify(stored_quote));
    

}
```

Comment: with this code I have to assume that you already have an array saved in your `localStorage` right? which is why you need to get whatever was in there first and save it in `stored_quote`

Comment: Unless you want to add an additional item, you do not need `    stored_quote.push(stored_quote[obj])`. `stored_quote` will have the updated value. 
You can always debug the values using `debugger` or logging them in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement `stored_quote.push(stored_quote[obj])` is causing the issue as you are pushing the updated object back into the array. Hence, it is duplicating it instead of overriding.

Hence, You don't need to push the object again. Instead, you can directly update the object in the array (which you already doing), and it will automatically reflect the changes.

Example **:**

```
function updateQuoteProduct(qP, qP_val) {

    var stored_quote = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("iwQuote")); 

    const index = stored_quote.findIndex((obj => obj.qid === qP));

    if (index !== -1) {
        stored_quote[index].qty = parseInt(qP_val)
        localStorage.setItem("iwQuote", JSON.stringify(stored_quote));
    }      
}
```

Comment: Jindal: I have been looking way to long to this and completely overlooked this one :( Thx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that after you update the object, you push the array again and it creates a duplicate object.

```
function updateQuoteProduct(qP, qP_val){
var stored_quote = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("iwQuote")); 

var objIndex = stored_quote.findIndex((obj => obj.qid === qP));

stored_quote[objIndex].qty = parseInt(qP_val);


localStorage.setItem("iwQuote", JSON.stringify(stored_quote));
```

}